# windows xp batch - check if printer exists

Tags: windows, windows-xp, batch

I am looking for a batch-function to check if a printer does already exist on a windows xp system.

I made up the following script:

```
set PRINTEREXISTS=0
For /F "Tokens=8 delims=\" %%I IN ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Printers" ^|find /I"r016-printer01"') Do (
    echo %%I
    set PRINTEREXISTS=1
)
if "%PRINTEREXISTS%"=="0" (
    echo Printer doesn't exist
) else (
    echo Printer exists
)
```

However, this sometimes outputs the printer name and then `Printer doesn't exist` even though it shouldn't because of `PRINTEREXISTS=1`... (NOT an issue of the reg query but with the batch-script somehow)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A batch file?  Why not a vbscript at least.  Something like:

```
strPrinterName ="r016-printer01"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Printer where name = '" & strPrinterName & "'")

If colPrinters.Count <> 0 Then

       wscript.echo "Printer exists" 

else

       wscript.echo "Printer doesn't exist"

End If
```